# inline lightbox pops up after 20 seconds

Tags: javascript, popup, fancybox, lightbox

Is there a lightbox that would allow me to tell it to pop up after a user has been on my site for 20 seconds (or other user defined time)?

I want to do it for a competition allowing the next 100 people to like us on facebook to be entered into a draw to win a prize.

Any ideas of a script that does this or how I could mod fancybox to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delay any action in javascript using the setTimeout method:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   // put code here you want to happen 20 seconds later
}, 20000); // time is in milliseconds
```

Comment: and of course, within the timeout you could use any number of lightbox plugins such as http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: How would i make the lightbox auto trigger in the first place ?

Answer (score -2):

You can do so using setTimeout function.

```
var time =2000;
setTimeout(function(){
    //piece of lightbox code goes here
}, time)
```

or you can do by page on load:

```
var loader = false;
var pagetimer = 2000;
$(window).on('load', function() {
    pageTimer = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!loader) {
            window.location.reload();
        }
        //set lightbox pop-up code here
    }, time);
```